# [C++ compile time assertions]: Can we throw a compilation error if some condition is not met?

Tags: c++, templates, assert, compile-time

I wrote a function:

```
template<int N> void tryHarder() {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        tryOnce();
    }
}
```

but I only want it to compile if N is in between 0 and 10. Can I do it? How?

Comment: Have a look at [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)

Comment: @juanchopanza: That is answer.

Comment: It looks great! But is there anything pre-C++11?

Answer (score 16):

You can do it with [`static_assert` declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static_assert):

```
template<int N> void tryHarder() {

    static_assert(N >= 0 && N <= 10, "N out of bounds!");

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        tryOnce();
    }
}
```

This feature is only avaliable since C++11. If you're stuck with C++03, take a look at [Boost's static assert macro](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html).

The whole idea of this are nice error messages. If you don't care for those, or can't even affor boost, you could do something as follows:

```
template<bool B>
struct assert_impl {
    static const int value = 1;
};

template<>
struct assert_impl<false> {
    static const int value = -1;
};

template<bool B>
struct assert {
    // this will attempt to declare an array of negative
    // size if template parameter evaluates to false
    static char arr[assert_impl<B>::value]; 
};

template<int N>
void tryHarder()
{
    assert< N <= 10 >();
}

int main()
{
    tryHarder<5>();  // fine
    tryHarder<15>();  // error, size of array is negative
}
```

Comment: This does assume that `N` is a compile time constant, tho'.

Comment: Made slightly simpler if you change it to `template<std::size_t N> void tryHader() { static_assert( N <= 10, "N out of bounds!" );`

Comment: @MatsPetersson as a template argument, it seems a safe assumption it is a compile time constant.

Comment: @Yakk Indeed, but I wanted to stick with what OP presented.

Answer (score 2):

For pre C++11 compilers, you could implement a template parameter constraint on the non-type parameter N.

For a description of how to do this, please see http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#constraints

Answer (score 1):

Combined with the answers given so far already, the lower bound can be covered, too, by using `unsigned int` as template type. Negative values, if applied, will be converted to unsigned values high enough that they will be covered with the `static_assert` or the pre-C++11 solution anyway.

`unsigned int` additionally gives already semantically a hint that negative values shall not be applied to this template, which is why it (possibly) should be preferred in the specific case...

Answer (score -2):

```
#if !defined(__cplusplus)
#error C++ compiler required.
#endif
```

This is just an example.

Here is the source link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8tk0xsk(v=vs.71).aspx

All i am saying is that you can use #error also

It is a directive

Edit @Pratik Chowdhruy: I agree with Paul R. This does not answer the question directly. Sorry to the community

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Look at the other answers to understand what the issue is here - the OP wants to know how to do a compile-time assert on a template parameter, not how to use conditional compilation and `#error`.

Comment: No problem - you might want to either edit your answer so that it answers the question or maybe delete it.

Comment: Paul R. You don't know. Trying to delete this answer just led to my near ban from StackOverflow. Or else, it won't be thewre maan cause I tried to undelete it and let you know, I am here to stay. Well anyway Sir are you one of the founding memebers of the stackoverflow, cause you called it your site. I'm very sorry to have offended you or the community. But, if you're not it's a very cheap prank. Just comment and I'll edit this comment Sir