# Google Mock testing::internal::ReturnAction<R> array with negative size

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have testing code which does something like

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, getSomeString()).WillOnce(Return(&testString));
```

where `getSomeString()` is returning by reference:

```
std:string& getSomeString();
```

and get

```
../../../../src/test/unit/gmock/gmock-actions.h: In member function ‘testing::internal::ReturnAction<R>::operator testing::Action<Func>() const [with F = const std::string&(), R = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]’:
../../../../src/test/unit/MyTests.cc:148:   instantiated from here
../../../../src/test/unit/gmock/gmock-actions.h:467: error: creating array with negative size (‘-0x00000000000000001’)
```

What is the cause?

Answer (score 25):

Check gmock-actions.h:467 and you'll see:

```
GMOCK_COMPILE_ASSERT_(
        !internal::is_reference<Result>::value,
        use_ReturnRef_instead_of_Return_to_return_a_reference);
```

So the answer is to use `ReturnRef` instead of `Return`:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, getSomeString()).WillOnce(ReturnRef(testString));
```

Comment: @feuGene. I agree that it's unhelpful, but I don't think it's googles fault. It's mostly a generally available way of generating a compile-time error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192575/c-compile-time-assertions-can-we-throw-a-compilation-error-if-some-conditio